# how use slidedown and slide up jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I wanted to show a car-info Class in a slidedown when the mouse is over it ... and conversely have it slide up on mouseout.
How can I do this in jquery?

```
 $(".items .title-bar").on("mouseover",this, function () {
        //how use car-info slide down
  });
  $(".items .title-bar").on("mouseout",this, function () {
        //i wanted  .title-bar and .car-info .. mouseout event and .car-info is slideup

});
```

before the `mouseover`

[image]

with `mouseover`

[image]

//see my jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/es3gx/

Comment: Try using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

Comment: What is `this` supposed to be in that code, you can't delegate to `this`?

Comment: how use css and jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should include jQuery libraries, then there are several errors (JS and CSS).

Look here:

```
$(".items .title-bar").on("mouseover", function () {
        $(this).closest(".items").find(".car-info").slideDown(); //@Vedant Terkar edit
});
$(".items .title-bar").on("mouseout", function () {
        $(this).closest(".items").find(".car-info").slideUp();   //@Vedant Terkar edit
});
```

and in CSS  you should remove z-index, and hide box using **display** attribute:

```
.car-info{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    display: none;    
}
```

Fiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/es3gx/5/

Comment: +1. Still need modifications. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: i wanted this style mouseout and mouseover

Comment: hey friend!! i wanted mouseout is .car-info after it is slide up

Comment: i' m not getting what do you expect. slide effect is actually on mouseout/mouseover. look at the demo http://jsfiddle.net/es3gx/5/

Comment: hello are you ok myfriends

Comment: how use multiple items use .. nex please give me

Comment: hello.. why your change you answer.. i wanted your answer.. plsease give me

Answer (score 2):

Just Variant of @pumpkinzzz Answer,

Here it'll only `slideUp` / `slideDown` the relevant `div`.

Use:

```
$(".items .title-bar").on("mouseover", function () {
        $(this).closest(".items").find(".car-info").slideDown();  // .closest means nearest parent with that attribute and .find means child within that parent with specified attribute.
            //how use car-info slide down
});
$(".items .title-bar").on("mouseout", function () {
            $(this).closest(".items").find(".car-info").slideUp();
});
```

Here is [***`Fiddle`***](http://jsfiddle.net/es3gx/4/).

Also according to your comment, I've created a new [**`Fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/es3gx/7/)

In that I've added `z-index` and `position:absolute` to various elements. So here is your changed `css`:

```
.car-info{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); /* changed for attractiveness */
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    display: none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;  /* Added to float car-info on car-image */   
    height:270px;
    overflow:auto;
    clear:both;
}
.photos-wrap{
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute; /* Added to Absolutely position car-photo beneath car-info */ 
    top:62px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:5; /* Added to float car-info on car-image  Any value< z-index of .car-info is acceptable */ 
    display:inline-block; /* Just changed */
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/es3gx/7/)

Hope It'll Satisfy your need.

Comment: @NyaungBinHla, See New Fiddle Link

Comment: yes sir. your answer is very good,. i wanted slideup is when .car-info class mouseover

Comment: @NyaungBinHla, At last I've fixed it. Have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/es3gx/11/

Answer (score 1):

you need to change in `css` and `jquery`

```
$(".items .title-bar").on("mouseenter",this, function () {
            //how use car-info slide down
    console.log($(this).next());
    $(this).next().slideDown();
});
$(".items .title-bar").on("mouseleave",this, function () {
            //how use car-info slide up
    $(this).next().slideUp();
});
```

CSS

```
.car-info{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;

    padding: 15px 10px;

    text-align: justify;
    z-index: -1;
    display:none;

}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/es3gx/3/)

Comment: yes sir. your answer is very good,. i wanted slideup is when .car-info class mouseover

Answer (score 1):

Again mouseenter and mouseleave are probably the best options, maybe try something like the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/dxZ5N/

```
$( ".items" ).mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find(".photos-wrap").slideDown();
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".photos-wrap").slideUp();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".items .title-bar").hover(function () {
        $(this).next('div.car-info').slideDown(700);
            //how use car-info slide down
}, function () {
             $(this).next('div.car-info').slideUp(700);
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/WLAup/